# Defining new variable before elif statement that is used as a condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to define a certain logic with `if-elif-else` statement. But it seems that what seems logical to me turns out to be invalid syntax. And I can't really understand why. I suppose there is a rather simple answer to this.

I wrote some logic as follows:

```
mylist = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa']

for index, element in enumerate(mylist):
    if index == len(mylist)-1:
        # Case: this is the last element
        pass

    myvar = mylist[index+1]
    elif len(myvar) == 2:
        # Case: this is not the last element and the next element length is 2
        pass

    else:
        # Case: this is not the last element and the next element length is not 2 ()
        pass
```

The problem is with definition of `myvar` and the consequent `elif` statement. This code gives invalid syntax, and pycharm defines it as 'Illegal target for variable annotation'. The question is: why can't the `myvar` be defined right before the `elif` statement. Does all conditions has to be predefined before executing the statement even tho the code might not get to a certain `elif` statement? Or there simply can't be any extra code in between `if-elif-else` parts? In this case `myvar` can't be predefined because it might be out of range.

As a solution I made it like this:

```
for index, element in enumerate(mylist):
    if index == len(mylist) - 1:
        # Case: this is the last element
        pass
    else:
        myvar = mylist[index + 1]
        if len(myvar) == 2:
            # Case: this not the last element and the length of next element is 2
            pass

        else:
            # Case: this is not the last element and the length of next element is not 2
            pass
```

Comment: Because that dedented `myvar = ...` line logically ends the `if ...` block. The following `elif` is not part of the preceding `if` chain, because that chain has been interrupted by another statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can't be any extra code in between `if-elif-else`. So you should just put `myvar` before the `if-elif-else`.

```
for index, element in enumerate(mylist):
    myvar = mylist[index+1]
    if index == len(mylist) - 1:
        pass
    elif len(myvar) == 2:
        pass
```

Comment: I understand now the problem. Also in this particular case that variable cannot be predefined because it will be out of range when running for loop for the last time.